# acceleration formula of parametric curve?

Tags: parametric, curves, bezier-curve, convergence-acceleration

I have a parametric curve as follows:

```
x(t)= 0.236t³-0.645t²+0.909t+0
```

`y(t)= 0.189t³-0.792t²+0.603t+0`

which looks like:

[image]

Now, I want to find the acceleration of this curve, from when it starts at 0,0 and ends at .5,0. HOW would I do this? It has been years since i took a math course, and I have spent hours and hours on  google trying to figure this out but I cant. can someone please help me in lehmans terms?? thanks in advance!

Comment: If $p(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, then the acceleration is defined as $p''(t) = (x''(t), y''(t))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The acceleration is the second derivative of position. As such, the acceleration in the x direction would be x''(t), and the acceleration in the y direction would be y''(t).